# how to use fade in and fade button both instead of using fade toggle

Tags: jquery, html

This is the code i am dealing with,and i want to use both fade in and fade out button but having problem as i don't know what id to pass for second button here is the code with jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button:first").click(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
    $("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
});
$("button:b2").click(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeOut();
    $("#div2").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#div3").fadeOut(3000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>

<button id="b1">Click to fade in boxes</button><br><br>
<button id="b2">Click to fade out boxes</button><br><br>


<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div><br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div><br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `id` of corresponding button to make it work

```
$("button#b2").click(function() {
```

Working fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/1jtbaeqb/

***Note:-*** In your current code case `:last` will also correct

```
$("button:last").click(function() {
```

Working fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/0ptjf7be/

Note:- fadeToggle() modified version is also applicable:-https://jsfiddle.net/hrt1jr86/  (I know you not needed but for your knowledge sake)

Answer (score 2):

Replace your 2nd button click function to : -

```
$("button:last").click(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeOut();
    $("#div2").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#div3").fadeOut(3000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more straightforward:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#b1").click(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
    $("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
});
$("#b2").click(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeOut();
    $("#div2").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#div3").fadeOut(3000);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>

<button id="b1">Click to fade in boxes</button><br><br>
<button id="b2">Click to fade out boxes</button><br><br>


<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div><br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div><br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div>
```